# FFT time segment

Tags: fft

When I use `scipy.signal.spectrogram` to calculate the spectrogram, with FFT size 2048, hop length 512, it return a time array which start with 1024 and increase 512 each time.

Why not it begins with 2048, I have set the FFT size 2048?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sounds like a bug, or you're not using it correctly

Comment: (that means this is more of a software development / programming than a signal processing question; it's inanswerable without code, but would, with, be better off on Stackoverflow.com)